# Work done without pre-approval, should I pay this guy?

Tags: sprinkler-system

Long story short, have a rental in another state managed by an RE agent. Recently she sent someone to look at the sprinkler system because multiple heads are not working properly. She was expecting to get a quote and consult with me for any work costing >$300. But the guy got there, did the work on the spot without consulting anyone and sent us a bill afterwards. It was a hefty bill to say the least. 2-3X more so than what I’d expect to pay for similar work. I told the agent to go negotiate but she was little help and kept saying she believed the guy was honest and did good work and that some of her other clients have him mow their lawns… She thinks I should just pay him. She sent me some videos and pictures of sprinklers heads but they don’t really tell me how much work is involved. What’s a fair going rate to replace 1 sprinkler nozzle? I’ve previously fixed and replaced many myself for little money by going to HomeDepot. This guy’s been harassing me for the last few weeks asking me to pay, am I legally entitled to pay him anything in this instance? What recourse does he have against me if I don’t pay him the whole amount?

Also to put things in context, I’ve previously received a quote from this guy based on the agent’s recommendation for some other work, it was high. I ended up finding someone to do the same work for 1/3 of his quote. Since then, I’ve been very skeptical of this guy.

Comment: This is more of a legal question. For example in Switzerland a contractor has to give you an offer which includes the work and the price. If you accept the offer the contractor has to do the work and you have to pay the price. Also seems like your RE agent is useless I would fire her.

Comment: Legal/contractual questions are off topic here. If you don't have a contract of any sort you don't have an obligation to pay. I'd pay for materials only out of basic decency if that's what you had expected to do anyway, or pay some portion of the labor if you're grateful that you don't have to do the work yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the problem with reliable, quality vendors. They charge a lot.  It's almost like they consider good work they stand behind to be valuable or something.  I don't know what world they think they're living in!

Comment: Time to take a hard look at the property manager. Is she taking "referral fees" aka kickbacks from contractors that she hires for the properties that she manages? Does your property management agreement explicitly prohibit that practice?

Answer (score 1):

So, from a legal perspective you don't have to pay the guy. From a moral perspective, you don't have to pay the guy. But from a "what is this guy gonna do" perspective that's a judgment call.

I'd ask someone else to look at things and tell them you're doing it to know the state of the system before you tell the first guy you aren't paying him because you never authorized work. That way you have a 3rd party documenting the state of things before you tell the guy who did the unauthorized work to either take reasonable compensation or return it to it's original state. (now this approach does assume the first guy isn't the best guy for 100 miles or something, and the second guy isn't the worst guy in town. You do get what you pay for.

Then I'm hiring a new property manager.

Comment: The last line is the key. The contractor may, or may not, have been honest about everything. But the property manager *should* have made it clear "If the work will be more than $300, I must get approval first", and if the property manager didn't do that then arguably anything above $300 should be their responsibility. But realistically: Pay the bill and fire the manager.

Comment: Agree guys. I do plan on paying the guy maybe about half of what he invoiced since based on the bid for a previous job, he wanted 3X of what I paid for someone else to do the job. So even at 50% I’m probably overpaying, but whatever. I agree on the PM, time for someone else after the contract term is up.

Comment: The property manager is hired to prevent these type of things.  You should have a clause in your management contract that spells out how much the PM is allowed to authorize without your approval.  They  have a fiduciary duty to work in your best interest.  They didn't.  They want you to pay so the vendor doesn't harass them.  Good advise, pay 1/2 and fire the PM.

Answer (score -1):

If you only had one sprinkler head replaced, I would expect it to cost less than $100 if all that was involved was simply removing the old head and installing a new one.  But if the supply pipe had to be repaired or other work was done, it just depends upon what was done. A decent contractor will provide the costs for labor and supplies separately so you can see what you are being charged for.

The one thing I would suggest is that you try to determine whether the guy who did the work was a licensed contractor or if the company he works for engages in legal hiring practices.  (If he is just a guy who does odd-jobs, then this does not apply unless you want to ask if he is legally able to work in the U.S.)  Any contractor that employs illegal workers (i.e. undocumented) and pays them cash under-the-table will be able to offer lower prices than a business that only hires legal employees and pays them at least minimum wage.  Because of this, I am glad to pay double what an illegal business charges for a service to have the work done by a contractor who obeys the law.  It is the millions of people who are only concerned about saving a buck that make it almost impossible for honest contractors to survive.  What you might think of as being a dishonest charge could just be the cost of doing business legally.  If your experience has been with dishonest contractors (not a criticism of you - most people never bother to ask), your idea of what it "should" cost might be somewhat biased or unrealistic.

I know this is meandering off-topic, but I just wanted you to think about why the cost of replacing a sprinkler might seem a lot higher than the $20 you spent at Home Depot to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for responding, this vendor is in landscaping and tree services. They wouldn’t be who I contact for sprinkler repairs. But the PM contacted them and I was the last one to find out about this work and the bill. I can’t judge on their work quality but the cost is high.